# SORM: How can I manage if String should be VARCHAR or CLOB?

Tags: scala, sorm

I have read in documentation "if string field is indexed it is VARCHAR(255), otherwise it is CLOB"

What if I wouldn't like to index field, but need VARCHAR representation?
For example:

```
case class User(login: String, passwordHash: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, country: String, city: String, aboutMe: String);
```

Only login and email is indexed, but passwordHash, firstName, lastName, country, city shouldn't be CLOB, because it is short fields and CLOB is overpower for them. How can I mark this fields as VARCHAR? Otherwise, aboutMe can contain long text, so it should be CLOB. How can I restrict lenght of VARCHAR field if I don't need max (255 characters)? For example, passwordHash couldn't be longer than 32 characters (depending on hashing method, of cource)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

An overhead of a `CLOB` value declaration over `VARCHAR` is just a couple of bytes. Philosophy behind SORM is it's all conventions over configuration. This approach is the cornerstone of how the elimination of boilerplate is achieved in SORM. Since in this day and age a couple of extra gigabytes - which may be the result of this overhead for a filled db - for storage space is hardly an issue, it's been decided to go with these settings for maximum compatibility.

Because of SORM's approach to the boilerplate there are no methods for you to fine tune these things exposed by the API. Although they may appear in the future, if the issue gets a notable attention, probably as additional properties of the `Entity`.

If you however insist on having a control over such things, there exists a quite simple solution: you let SORM generate the schema the way it does and then using the database administration tool of your choice you fine tune your db by altering columns, indexes or whatever. Switching between the text-types of columns (CLOB, VARCHAR and etc) shouldn't cause any troubles.

Comment: Thank you very much. Of course I don't care about few additional bytes, but what about performance? Is CLOB as fast as VARCHAR? Isn't there any performance drawbacks connected with CLOB?

Comment: As long as you don't use a `CLOB` column in "where" or "order" clauses, there shouldn't be any noticable difference. If however you do, you should specify those columns as indexes anyway, which will result in them being converted to `VARCHAR`. So, you see, it's all covered )